# I can't figure out pip tensorrt line 17 error

Tags: python, windows, pip, nvidia, tensorrt

I couldn't install it in any way, I wonder what could be the cause of the error.

I installed C++ and other necessary stuff

I am using windows 11

I installed `pip install nvidia-pyindex` with no problem.
Same as tensorrt I can't install pycuda library and I get same error

```
\`
(base) PS C:\\Users\\byara\> pip install nvidia-tensorrt
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Collecting nvidia-tensorrt
Downloading nvidia-tensorrt-0.0.1.dev5.tar.gz (7.9 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> \[17 lines of output\]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\<string\>", line 2, in \<module\>
File "\<pip-setuptools-caller\>", line 34, in \<module\>
File "C:\\Users\\byara\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ak3sxwfw\\nvidia-tensorrt_a7512906bd3241728853c0e6a10bf9d4\\setup.py", line 150, in \<module\>
raise RuntimeError(open("ERROR.txt", "r").read())
RuntimeError:
\###########################################################################################
The package you are trying to install is only a placeholder project on PyPI.org repository.
This package is hosted on NVIDIA Python Package Index.

     This package can be installed as:
    `
     $ pip install nvidia-pyindex
     $ pip install nvidia-tensorrt
    `your text`
     ###########################################################################################
   
     [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─\> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
\`
```

Answer (score 1):

TensorRT is not available for Windows via pip. You can verify that by looking at the wheel files in PyPI, [link](https://pypi.org/project/nvidia-tensorrt/#files). All the wheel files for the latest version are for Linux. Thus, trying to install on Windows will pick the previous releases, which were place-holder packages. Those releases just print the message you are seeing, on all OSes.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/install-guide/index.html)

> The zip file is the only option currently for Windows.

You can find instructions on how to install at [Zip File Installation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/install-guide/index.html#installing-zip).