# ''tensorrt'' not install with pip

Tags: python, tensorrt

I'm trying to install `tensorrt` with pip and the following message is appearing :

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to use the command :

```
pip install nvidia-tensorrt
pip install torch-tensorrt
```

I am using `Python 3.8.1rc1`

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74520032/i-cant-figure-out-pip-tensorrt-line-17-error

Comment: What is your OS version, Python version etc.?